# Where exactly are those eight steep slopes on Mars revealing structures of buried ice?

Tags: mars, water, geology, ice

[image: steep slope]
Credit:NASA/JPL-Caltech/UA/USGS

The image above is from Phys.org's article [Steep slopes on Mars reveal structure of buried ice](https://phys.org/news/2018-01-deep-glaciers-mars.html) that I came upon by the link in a comment from @Mark Adler after [his answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27785/is-there-any-economical-way-to-move-the-water-from-the-martian-poles-to-the-peop/27954#27954) to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27785/is-there-any-economical-way-to-move-the-water-from-the-martian-poles-to-the-peop).

It shows **one of the eight scarps** that researchers using the Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter have found where thick deposits of ice are exposed in faces of their eroding slopes.
Those eight sites are at latitudes from about 55 to 58 degrees but their exact location is not revealed in that article.

Answer (score 8):

### Scarp #1:

According to [this NASA information](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/details.php?id=PIA22078), this specific scarp is located at 56.6 degrees South latitude, 114.1 degrees East longitude. This picture was taken on May 7, 2011.

I went to Google Earth Pro, and inputted the coordinates: -56.6, 114.1 on Mars, and it looks the same. Note the "wedge" shape.

[image]

[image]

### Scarp #2:

[Here's another one of those 8 scarps](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/24781/ice-exposing-scarps/). At coordinates 55.309, 253.45.

[image]

This is a cropped image. Circled by me. The [original photo](https://hirise-pds.lpl.arizona.edu/PDS/EXTRAS/RDR/ESP/ORB_062800_062899/ESP_062853_2355/ESP_062853_2355_RED.browse.jpg) can be found [here](https://www.uahirise.org/ESP_062853_2355).

On Google Earth Pro, you can find it by inputting the above coordinates.

[image]

### Scarp #3:

[Located at Milankovič Crater](https://www.uahirise.org/ESP_028121_2355). Located at 55.212, 213.103.

[image]

Here's the Google Earth Pro image:

[image]

Comment: That's a good start, only seven more to go for !

Comment: I'll keep updating my answer as I find more. Just found the second.

Comment: @Cornelisinspace I have made my answer into a community wiki.

Comment: Those wedges and scarps remind me a bit of the [burning ship fractal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2322660/284619)

Answer (score 7):

**Table S1** in [the supplement](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/suppl/2018/01/11/359.6372.199.DC1/aao1619-Dundas-SM.pdf) of [this article in Science](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/359/6372/199.full) gives the locations of the 7 scarps in the southern hemisphere and the multiple scarps in [Milankovic crater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milankovic_(Martian_crater)) north of Olympus Mons.
Scarp 1 to 7 are all situated southeast of Hellas basin within latitudes 55⁰ - 58.1⁰ S and longitudes 89⁰ - 114.1⁰ E

### Scarp 1 ( 56.6⁰S, 114.1⁰E )

See the other answer.

### Scarp 2 ( 55.1⁰S, 109.4⁰E )

[image: Scarp 2]

Part from  https://uahirise.org/ESP_065206_1245
(Click on the image, and then again, for a closer view)

**Notification: Scarp #2 in the other answer is another new one not mentioned in Table S1.**

### Scarp 3 ( 58.1⁰S, 93.7⁰E )

[image: Scarp 3]

Part from https://uahirise.org/ESP_040772_1215
(Click on the image, and then again, for a closer view)

### Scarp 4 ( 55.0⁰S, 108.9⁰E )

[image: Scarp 4]

Part from https://uahirise.org/ESP_022943_1245
(Click on the image, and then again, for a closer view)

### Scarp 5 ( 57.2⁰S, 89.8⁰E )

[image: Scarp 5]

Part from https://uahirise.org/ESP_049198_1225
(Click on the image, and then again, for a closer view)

### Scarp 6 ( 56.9⁰S, 96.3⁰E )

[image: Scarp 6]

Part from https://uahirise.org/ESP_057677_1230
(Click on the image, and then again, for a closer view)

### Scarp 7 (57.5⁰S, 91.9⁰E )

[image: Scarp 7]

Part from https://uahirise.org/ESP_065510_1220
(Click on the image, and then again, for a closer view)

### Milankovic crater ( 54.8⁰N, 148⁰W ) (multiple scarps)

[image: Multiple scarps]
Part from https://uahirise.org/ESP_024943_2345
(Click on the image, and then again, for a closer view)

More scarps in Milankovic crater on the following images:
https://uahirise.org/ESP_068104_2350
https://uahirise.org/ESP_062815_2345
https://uahirise.org/ESP_061048_2340
https://uahirise.org/ESP_061127_2345
https://uahirise.org/ESP_063962_2345
https://uahirise.org/ESP_063751_2350
https://uahirise.org/ESP_053175_2350
https://uahirise.org/ESP_053452_2340
https://uahirise.org/ESP_071652_2360

With many thanks to the [HiRISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HiRISE) !

Comment: Could you put the information in your answer, so it is not link-only?

Comment: @DrSheldon  Good idea, give me some time and I will look for HiRISE images of the 7 scarps in the  southern hemisphere.